# Is "against" appropriate in this context?

Tags: prepositions

This is from [a news article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/arts-entertainment/2022/04/10/johnny-depp-amber-heard-case/#O47DR7OJSFGTTDAPJDXIIHQFJI-1) :

> In April 2019, Heard filed to dismiss the case and detailed years of
> alleged abuse beginning in late 2012, when she said he first slapped
> her across the face. She alleged that Depp abused drugs and alcohol
> and called him “the Monster” during these times, and said she never
> attacked Depp except in self-defense **against** her and her sister.

Considering the meaning of preposition "**[against](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/against)**", I think that it should be replaced with 'of' in this context.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original isn't great, but your suggestion is wrong, too.

It **is** possible to do something in defence '*of*' someone - that means you're defending them.

It **isn't** possible to do something in *self-defence* of someone, because self-defence is defending yourself *against* an attack from someone else.

In the example, the speaker is talking about someone defending themselves (self-defence) and another person, so what they really should have said is "*in defence of herself and her sister*".

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: But the defence was against her husband, not 'against' herself and sister. I think the writer should have said _in defence of herself and her sister_ or _in self-defence and to protect her sister_.

Comment: I don't agree. The context is sufficiently unusual / non-standard that we can't really identify a single "correct" preposition. I find ***of*** at least "acceptable" in the cited context, but I'm perfectly happy with ***against*** (or ***for***, and perhaps other prepositions). Or as @KateBunting says, rephrase to get rid of the problems created by ***self**-defence*.

Comment: @KateBunting You're correct. I purely addressed the question of "am I wrong?" and the OP's suggestion was incorrect for the reasons I've given. I have expanded my answer to state the correct way.

Comment: OK - have removed my downvote.

Comment: @Astralbee Thank you very much. I found this sentence on the web : ["_Detectives with the Stanislaus County Sheriff's Office are currently investigating a shooting in which a Patterson homeowner fired a revolver **in self-defense of her husband** who was fighting to keep an intoxicated intruder out of their residence._"](https://www.cbsnews.com/sacramento/news/woman-fatally-shoots-intoxicated-man-trying-to-break-into-home/)

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you very much.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much.

Comment: In self-defense against attackers, terrorists, etc. is well attested. There is nothing wrong with it. Oxford University: https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:f794ea71-baf3-46fd-bf78-8533ba84e230/files/mab0135360c45fd5ec3872ccc50583df1

Comment: @Elise in self-defense of her husband means she was **helping him** fight someone off.

Comment: @ellse Regarding the news report you found - I still have to say that it is not logical to say someone acted in 'self-defence' of anyone but themself. However, in US law, "self-defence" is a stance that is used to justify the use of force by one person against another person under specific circumstances. So this particular article could be understood that the person acted "in self-defence" from a legal standpoint, protecting themself and others.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you very much.

Comment: @Astralbee I understand. Thank you very much.